# Как в gorilla/websocket в подключение добавить хедер с кукой?

Tags: http, golang, websocket, header

Я пытаюсь добавить хедер в соединение по вебсокетам, но видимо я что-то кардинально не то делаю. Вот кусок, где я добавляю хедер:

```
cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "sid", Value: "f5d00xvcb5568b375ad33423f28ec297"}

var h http.Header
h.Set("Cookie", cookie.String())

c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), h)
```

Но возникает паника "panic: assignment to entry in nil map" после попытки установить хедер с нужным значением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.Header` является хеш-таблицей, а хеш-таблицы в го
являются типами-ссылками, которые надо инициализировать.  Как-то
так:

```golang
var h = make(http.Header, 1)
h.Set("Cookie", cookie.String())
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Очень помогло.